# How to effectively communicate between database bound applications?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, inter-process-communicat

We have a number of different old school client-server C# WinForm client-side apps that are essentially front-ends for the database.  Then there is a C# server-side windows service that waits on the client apps to submit orders and then it processes them.

The way the server-side service finds out whether there is work to do is that it polls the database.  Over the years the logic of polling for waiting orders has gotten a lot more complicated due to the myriad of business rules.  So because of this, the polling stored proc itself uses quite a bit of SQL Server resources even if there is nothing to do.  Add to this the requirement that the orders be processed the moment they are submitted and you got yourself a performance problem, as the database is being polled constantly.

The setup actually works fine right now, but the load is about to go through the roof and, it is obvious, that it won't hold up.

What are some effective ways to communicate between a bunch of different client-side apps and a server-side windows service, that will be more future-proof than the current method?

The database server is SQL Server 2005.  I can probably get the powers that be to pony up for latest SQL Server if it really comes to that, but I'd rather not fight that battle.

Comment: Does the communication have to be done via the database or can the clients communicate with the service using another way?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos All options are on the table.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a good idea, but setting a mutex from a CLR routine invoked by a stored procedure or trigger may be something to look at.  From a design standpoint I hate it, but it might minimize changes on the client side and allow you to test the notifications fairly well before switching over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous options ways you can notify the clients.

- You can use a ready-made solution like [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/), to publish information from the server to the clients or other servers. NServiceBus uses MSMQ to publish one message to multiple subscribers in a very easy and durable way.
- You can use MSMQ or another queuing product to publish messages from the server that will be delivered to the clients.
- You can host a WCF service on the Windows service and connect to it from each client using a Duplex channel. Each time there is a change the service will notify the appropriate clients or even all of them. This is more complex to code but also much more flexible. You could probably send enough information back to the clients that they wouldn't need to poll the database at all.
- You can have the service broadcast a UDP packet to all clients to notify them there are changes they need to pull. You can probably add enough information in the packet to allow the clients to decide whether they need to pull data from the server or not. This is a very lightweight for the server and the network, but it assumes that all clients are in the same LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can leverage [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) to receive notifications only when the data actually changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any messaging middleware like MSMQ, JMS or TIBCO to communicate between your client and the service.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest, and most likely the cheapest, answer is to simply buy a bigger server.

Barring that, you are in for a development effort that has a high probability of early failure.  By failure I don't mean that you end up scraping whatever it is you end up building.  Rather, I mean you launch the changes and orders will be screwed up while you are debugging your myriad of business rules.

Quite frankly, I wouldn't consider approaching a communications change under pressure; presuming your statement about load going "through the roof" in the near term.

If your risk exposure is such that it has to be 100% functional day one (which is normal when you are expecting a large increase in orders), with no hiccups then just upsize the DB server.  Heck, I **wouldn't** even install the latest sql server on it.  Instead, just buy a larger machine, install the exact same OS and DB server (and patch levels) and move your database.

Then look at your architecture to determine what needs to go away and what can be salvaged.

Comment: I don't think this would work in this scenario.  There would be far too many deadlocks, waits, etc... as everyone would be hitting the same data.  Though I should probably try it to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If everybody connects to SQL Server then there is also the option of [Service Broker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166104%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Unlike other messaging/queueing solution recommended so far it is entirely contained in your database (no separate product to deploy, administer and configure), it offers a single story vis-a-vis your backup/recovery and high availability needs ( no separate backup for message store, no separate DR/HA, whatever is your DB solution is also your messaging solution) and overs a uniform programming API (SQL).

Even when everything is within one single SQL Server instance (ie. there is no need to communicate over network between multiple SQL Service instances) Service Broker still has an ace that no one can match: [activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). With activation you eliminate completely the need to poll because the system itself will launch your processing code (will 'activate') when there are events to process. The processing code can be internal (T-SQL procedure or SQLCLR .Net procedure) or external (see [external activator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/archive/2008/11/21/announcing-service-broker-external-activator.aspx)).